# check if elements of string exist in another string

Tags: shell, ash

I have two strings:

```
l1='a1 a2 b1 b2 c1 c2'
l2='a1 b3 c1'
```

And I want to check if each element of string `l2` exists in `l1`, and then remove it from `l1`.

Is it possible to do that without a `for` loop?

Comment: It would be better to use an array rather than a string.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
l1=$(comm -23 <(echo "$l1" | tr ' ' '\n' | sort) <(echo "$l2" | tr ' ' '\n' | sort) | tr '\n' ' ')
```

The [`comm`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/comm) compares lines and outputs the lines that are unique to the first input, unique to the second input, and common to both. The `-23` option suppresses the second two sets of outputs, so it just reports the lines that are unique to the first input.

Since it requires the input to be sorted lines, I first pipe the variables to `tr` to put each word on its own line, and then `sort` to sort it. `<(...)` is a common shell extension called [process substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution) that allows a command to be used where a filename is expected; it's available in `bash` and `zsh`, for example (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_command_shells#Inter-process_communication) for a table that lists which shells have it).

At the end I use `tr` again to translate the newlines back to spaces.

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/WskKn9)

If you don't have process substution, you can emulate it with named pipes:

```
mkfifo p1
echo "$l1" | tr ' ' '\n' | sort > p1 &
mkfifo p2
echo "$l2" | tr ' ' '\n' | sort > p2 &
l1=$(comm p1 p2 | tr '\n' ' ')
rm p1 p2
```

Comment: with bash it's OK but with ash it's not !

Comment: I've added how to emulate it with named pipes.

Comment: Why doesn't it work? What OS are you using? I'm assuming it's some form of Unix or Linux, they should all have `comm`.

Comment: Sounds like you may have to resort to a loop, then. There's nothing built into the shell to do this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71853/discussion-between-stack-a-and-barmar).